# Mongocxx fails to connect to mongoDB with SSL

Tags: c++, mongodb, ssl, mongo-cxx-driver

I completed the following tutorial (https://medium.com/@rajanmaharjan/secure-your-mongodb-connections-ssl-tls-92e2addb3c89) to set up self-signed SSL certificates to secure communications between a device and a server hosting a mongoDB database.

I can access the database from the server and from the device with the following command:

`mongo --ssl --sslCAFile /path/to/CA.pem --sslPEMKeyFile /path/to/mongodb.pem --host IP:port`

## Error

When I try to connect to the database with a C++ program, I get a seg fault:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Output from GDB is

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000007fb7f6d6a8 in mongocxx::v_noabi::client::client(mongocxx::v_noabi::uri const&, mongocxx::v_noabi::options::client const&) () from /usr/local/lib/libmongocxx.so._noabi`

## C++ code

I instanciate the connection with:

```
mongocxx::instance instance{};

mongocxx::options::ssl ssl_opts;
ssl_opts.pem_file("/path/to/mongodb.pem");
// ssl_opts.allow_invalid_certificates(false); // I have tried this

mongocxx::options::client client_opts;
client_opts.ssl_opts(ssl_opts);

auto client = mongocxx::client{mongocxx::uri{"mongodb://user:pwd@IP:port/?authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&ssl=true"}, client_opts};
```

And compile with the following command:

`c++ --std=c++11 main.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx) -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib`

I have not been able to fix this error or find a solution online, any help would be much appreciated.

### Additional Information

Versions:

Mongo c - 1.10.1

Mongo cxx - 3.3.0

Backtrace:

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fb7ff4000 (LWP 17800)):
#0  0x0000007fb7f6d6a8 in 
mongocxx::v_noabi::client::client(mongocxx::v_noabi::uri const&, 
mongocxx::v_noabi::options::client const&) () from 
/usr/local/lib/libmongocxx.so._noabi
#1  0x00000000004027d0 in main ()
```

Comment: Please update with the version of the C driver and the C++ driver that you are using. Also helpful would be the full backtrace from your application, get this with `thread apply all bt` in GDB.

Comment: I updated the question. There is not much happening apart from the code that I posted, it is the first thing that is run in my main.cpp file and it crashes at the `auto client ...` line.

Comment: Are you building the C driver and C++ driver from source, or did you get them from a package manager (if so, which one, etc.). Can you update the C driver to 1.13 and re-test?

Comment: I am building the drivers from the Github source. I updated to 1.13.0 and got the following result:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of mongocxx::v_noabi::logic_error
  what():  an invalid MongoDB URI was provided
Aborted (core dumped)`

If I change the URI to `...@IP:port/?ssl=true` I get 

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: The `Segmentation fault` is the same as previously when run through GDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [known serious bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-1614) with passing `options::ssl_opts` to the client constructor in the C++ driver version 3.3.0 causing the segfault. This is fixed in 3.3.1. It is highly recommended that you upgrade.

As a workaround for 3.3.0, you can pass the pem_file option through the URI string. The URI option `"sslclientcertificatekeyfile"` corresponds to the `options::ssl::pem_file` option. E.g:

```
auto uri = mongocxx::uri{"mongodb://localhost/?ssl=true&sslclientcertificatekeyfile=/path/to/mongodb.pem"};
```

But do upgrade to 3.3.1 if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will do the update on Monday and get back to you.

Comment: I updated mongocxx to 3.3.1 and mongoc to 1.13 (as per acm's recommandation) and passed the ssl option .allow_invalid_certificates(true) and I am now able to connect to my DB via SSL with self-signed certificates. Thank you for your help!